# How to display variable value in Report.html file of RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

How to display variable value in Report.html file of RobotFramework.
I am using RIDE

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read through the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html), and looked through the list of [built-in keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're using RIDE is irrelevant, just so you know. RIDE is just a Robot Framework test data editor and doesn't influence the execution itself.

Now to answer your actual question, you could simply use the `Log` keyword from the BuiltIn library.

```
Log    ${my_variable_name}
```

However this will display your variable in the log file, rather than in the report file. The report file is meant to be a summary report and I'm not sure why you'd want to log a variable's value in there, but if you insist on doing so, perhaps you could use the keyword `Set Test Documentation` to append your variable to the test's documentation, which is displayed in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Let ${result} be the variable, you want to display in the report.html file. Then, you can use the following keyword

```
Set Test Message       ${result}
```

If the ${result} variable is returned by the **RUN PROCESS** keyword, then you can use
${result.stdout}, ie,

```
Set Test Message       ${result.stdout}
```